# Do capitals in HTML affect the code?

Tags: html

I've noticed in some old html that a table I made, for some reason has the following code `<table cellSpacing="2">`

Would capitals in html affect the outcome of the code? I can imagine this affecting CSS for class and ID but what about HTML?

Could I essentially write `<table CELLSPACING="2">` and it would work the same as using lower case?

Comment: No, capitalization of HTML tags does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't affect the HTML - either case is ok and will not affect the page when rendered.